# exempting a piece of perl code from strict pragma

Tags: perl, dbi, strict, bareword

I have a legacy piece of perl code that uses [perl DBI](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::SQLite) with constructs like

```
$db->bind_param(1, $some_blob, {TYPE => SQL_BLOB});
```

where SQL_BLOB is a bareword.  I would like to use strict pragma in the same file, but it then complains about the bareword. ('Bareword "SQL_BLOB" not allowed while "strict subs" in use') Can I somehow exempt this line from strict checking?

Answer (score 6):

While you can indeed turn off the `strict` pragma, that's not going to fix your problem.  You're going to just pass the value "SQL_BLOB" as a type, but `bind_param` isn't going to recognize it.

You need to add an import:

```
use DBI qw(:sql_types);
```

If you're already `use`ing DBI, then add `:sql_types` to the things you import from it.

Answer (score 5):

The [strict pragma](https://perldoc.perl.org/strict) is lexical

> The effect of this pragma is limited to the current file or scope block.

and it can also be turned off within a scope.  So

```
use strict;

...

{
    no strict 'subs';

    $db->bind_param(1, $some_blob, {TYPE => SQL_BLOB});
}

# strict is back on
```

---

**Edit**

However, the above will only tolerate the bareword while [bind_param](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#bind_param) still won't know what that (integer constant) is. This is solved by `import`-ing such constant(s), by using the `:sql_types` [import tag](https://perldoc.perl.org/Exporter#Specialised-Import-Lists); see [DBI Constants](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#DBI-Constants).  That is anyway a far superior way to satisfy the `strict`.

Thanks to Andy Lester for bringing this up, see their [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66771485/4653379)

Comment: While this will indeed stop the warning, the program won't work.  See my answer below.

Comment: @AndyLester Thank you, I didn't know about type constants. Added a note

Comment: Using `$db->bind_param(1, $some_blob, {TYPE => "SQL_BLOB"});` would be better than turning off strict. (Of course, as you mention, this isn't actually correct.)

Comment: @ikegami Right. I take it that they can't touch that code (there may be a lot of it, complex, etc)

Comment: Thank you all, this really helps.